# What is OWIN equivalent for Application_EndRequest?

Tags: asp.net, owin

I am migrating an `ASP.NET Web API` application to `OWIN`. That is not intended to use none `OWIN` deployments. So `Global.asax` is going to be removed. There are some code put into `Global.asax` event handlers specially in `Application_EndRequest` that should be handled by `OWIN`.

I have read some article about `OWIN` and searched the internet but couldn't determine how it can be done. Can anyone please describe how it can be done?

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 RC
- .Net Framework 4.5
- Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.5.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.3
- Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1
- Owin.1.0

**UPDATE:** Here it is some sections of current code

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using ProjectX.Web.AppStart;
using ProjectY.Domain.Contracts;

namespace ProjectX.UI
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork)) as IUnitOfWork;

            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


namespace ProjectY.Domain.Contracts
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        void SaveChanges();
        IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class, IEntity, IHistory;
        IDbContext GetDbContext();
    }
}




using ProjectY.Core.Repositories;
using ProjectY.Domain.Contracts;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectY.Core.UnitOfWork
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public UnitOfWork(IProjectYDbContextFactory contextFactory)
        {
            _context = contextFactory.GetContext();
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            if (_context == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Something wrong has been happened. _context must not be null.");

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the kinds of things you are currently handling within your `EndRequest` handler? The answer will depend on the activities.

Comment: @Tragedian Unit of work pattern is ended via `Application_EndRequest`. It is indeed an `EF SaveChanges()`. I understand that it may be manageable via `Owin Context` but as our application is in the begining of the development I'm pretty sure that in future there will be scenarios that we should do some works in `Global.asax` event handlers.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works for you. Could you show the code which sets up and ends your unit-of-work?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question while updating some legacy applications. For those still seeking the answer: you can solve this by creating a middleware:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke().ConfigureAwait(false);
    //Do stuff after request here!
    var unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork)) as IUnitOfWork;
    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
});
```

You can use stage markers if you need more control on when your middleware will be called in the request processing pipeline.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline#stage-markers